# Hash and Unhash?

Tags: java, hash, bcrypt

Is it possible to Hash using bcrypt in java and again unhash it? Is it even possible? I was trying something new but I do not know anything about Unhashing (if it's possible). Can someone give me an example of somekind if it's possible?

Is there a hashing algorithm which is reversible if the key is known?

Comment: A reversible hashing is not a hash... Lossless compression might be considered (with quite a squint) a reversible hashing, but a very bad hashing IMHO...

Comment: Hashing is different than encryption. Look into encryption and decryption with keys.

Comment: You state "a hashing algorithm which is reversible if the key is known", and have tagged the question `bcrypt`. This suggests you are talking about Encryption, not hashing. It is important you use the correct terms as the differences are subtle but critically important.

Comment: The joker, could you even define `unhash`? Check `encrypt` and `decrypt`

Comment: uh I know about Encryption and Decryption, and I am talking about hashing and unhashing (which seems impossible now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about overriding hashCode(), if your object can have more than 2^32 states then it's impossible to make any reversible hash.  There are only 2^32 possible hash values (because hashCode() returns int), so only 2^32 different states can be represented.

Answer (score 5):

Hashing is a one-way operation by definition. You cannot retrieve source value from its cache. Actually there can be many values that produce the same hash but algorithm that translates hash to value should not exist theoretically (by definition).

Comment: Hash instead of cache *.